# Source code version number from android srouce code

Tags: android, version

I have android source code. how do i find out which version it belongs to?
Is there a file or build check which i can do which will determine the version of the android source code?

Comment: I think you should search keyword into os version in whole sourcecode?  Not sure where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get from application "project.properties" file

```
# Project target.
target=android-17 // 17 is 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Example Manifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.anon.apptest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: does not give the source code version of android.

Answer (score 0):

Get version in code:

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(
context.getPackageName(), 0);
String version = info.versionName;
```

Comment: i dont want to write an app to find out.. from android source code i need to find the version num.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the manifest file. You have there version and version code.

Comment: does not give the source code version of android.

Comment: ok, so you have the source code of android OS and not some android app source code. If you have the full code, check the class Build (android.os.Build.VERSION) and there you have VERSION which indicates the os version